# DialogFlow with Webhook Client: Error agent.getContext is not a function at IncomingMessage.resp

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am working on a DialogFlow project using Firebase Cloud function. 
I send a GET request to my API and I receive back data from the server, then display it on fulfillment text property. That's fine.

Now I need to store in a sort of "application variable" the cookie session id from the server, in order to keep track of the interactions between client and server.
I try to save the cookie session in a Context object, in doing so I get the error :

Agent.getContext is not a function at IncomingMessage.resp

Here is the code:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest( ( req, resp ) =>{

  const agent = new WebhookClient( {request: req, response: resp} );

  //SET CONTEXT HERE

  const context = {
    'name': 'sessione',
    'lifespan': 2,
    'parameters': {'idSessione': c.sessionID}
  };
  agent.setContext( context );

  if( context ){
    console.log( '*--*****************--  name context =' + context.name );
  }

  //...some stuff etc-

  //call my function to consume API

  callAVA( strRicerca ).then( ( strOutput ) =>{

    return resp.json( {'fulfillmentText': strOutput} );
  } ).catch( ( error ) =>{

    return resp.json( {'fulfillmentText': 'error error'} );

  } );
} );

// added parameter Agent-
function callAVA( agent, strRicerca ){
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{

    https.get( options, ( resp ) =>{

      //variable options contains set cookies values , host name etc-

      let data = '';

      // A chunk of data has been recieved.
      resp.on( 'data', ( chunk ) =>{
        data += chunk;

      } );

      // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
      resp.on( 'end', () =>{

        let c = JSON.parse( data );

        let strOutput = c.output[0].output;
        console.log( '----- ID DELLA SESSIONE : ' + c.sessionID );
        if( c.sessionID ){

          // I NEED TO SAVE IDSESSION FROM SERVER -

          let context = agent.getContext( 'sessione' );

          //  GOT  ERROR: agent.getContext is not a function at IncomingMessage.resp (????)


          context.parameters.idSessione = c.sessionID;
        }


        resolve( strOutput );

        //DO OTHER STUFF...
      } );

      resp.on( "error", ( err ) =>{
        console.log( "Error: " + err.message );

        reject( err.message );
      } );

    } );
  } );
}
```

Is there any other way to keep track of the user who is sending request to the server? I would prefer to keep things simple without accessing databases...Thanks a lot, any help would be really appreciated. :)

__________________________________EDIT________________________________
Putting context aside for a moment, I realize I am missing some points, so 
I've modify my code as follows according to your suggestions:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const https = require('http');


postData = querystring.stringify({
    'searchText': 'ciao',
    'user':'',
    'pwd':'',
    'ava':'FarmaInfoBot'

  });
   const options = {
    hostname: '86.107.98.69', 
    port: 8080, 
    path: ‘/mypath/search_2?searchText=', 
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
      'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData),
      'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=' // -> this comes from the server, store it in context, conv.data or what else-> to do
    }
  };

 exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((req, resp) => {

   const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: resp});

    let strRicerca='';
    if (req.body.queryResult.parameters['searchText']) {
      strRicerca=req.body.queryResult.parameters['searchText'];

        options.path+=strRicerca+'&user=&pwd=&ava=FarmaInfoBot';
    }

    /* IS THIS OK NOW TO INVOKE FUNCTION LIKE THIS, NOW THAT I ADDED AGENT ? */
   callAVA(agent, strRicerca).then((strOutput)=> {

        return resp.json({ 'fulfillmentText': strOutput }); 
    }).catch((error) => {

       return resp.json({ 'fulfillmentText': 'error!!!!!!!!!!'});

    });



function callAVA(agent, strRicerca) {
  return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {


     https.get(options, (resp) => {


        let data = '';
        console.log(`STATUS RESPONSE: ${resp.statusCode}`);
        console.log(`HEADERS RESPONSE: ${JSON.stringify(resp.headers)}`);

        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
            var c=JSON.parse(chunk);

        });
        resp.on('end', () => {


            let c=JSON.parse(data);

            let strOutput= agent.add('Static response from Agent'); // c.output[0].output;

            console.log(strOutput);


            resolve(strOutput);  


        });
         resp.on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);

            reject(err.message);
      });
     });

  });

}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('test_fb', callAVA);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Now the program is running but I receive an empty response, the crash happens in the end event, parsing Json data.
My aim at last is to find a way to save cookie from server in a global variable and keep it across conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are a few problems here.

The immediate cause if your error is that you have defined the `callAVA()` function as

```
function callAVA( agent, strRicerca )
```

but when you're calling it a few lines earlier, you are omitting the `agent` parameter:

```
callAVA( strRicerca )
```

However, there are other problems with how you're using it that will cause you problems in the long-run.

While what you're doing may be valid, and may work, it is also different than how processing typically works, and it may be that you may be causing some problems with this.

Typically, you create the `agent`, as you have, and then register Intent Handlers against it. Something like

```
let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('intent.name.1', intentHandlerFunction1);
intentMap.set('intent.name.2', intentHandlerFunction2);
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

which will call the matching function for the Intent name with a single parameter, the `agent`. (As an aside - good job returning a Promise! You have that part correct.)

As part of an Intent handler, you'll want to call `agent.setContext(context)` *before* your Promise finishes. In a later Intent handler, when you want to know the value, you need to call `agent.getContext('context-name')` which should return the entire Context object, including the remaining lifespan and the parameters for it..

**Update**

The change you made in your first edit isn't enough. The problem is that you're mixing two different ways to call the Intent Handler:

1. In one way, you're calling it directly with the second parameter. As part of the results, it is sending JSON to the `resp` object.
2. In the other way, you've registered it with `intentMap.set()` which is causing it to get called (with just the `agent` parameter) when `handleRequest()` is called and it is setting a response through the `agent` object.

In general, unless you want to manipulate all the JSON yourself, you should rely on method (2). You should **not** call the Intent Handler function directly yourself, but instead let `handleRequest()` handle it for you.

Since you need the `strRicerca` object, you can make that available in the same scope the function runs in, which it already seems to be. So you probably don't need to include it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks @Prisoner for your answer, could you pls check my answer out?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, now I've just edited my original question

Comment: Got it @Prisoner, method 2 is ok now, and I am passing only one argument, the web hook reference, that is the agent. Just a doubt: is it ok to return the agent from the function callAVA? I mean:
agent.add(strOutput); 
 resolve(agent);

Comment: To be clear - you're not returning the agent. You're returning a Promise, and that Promise is resolving an agent. That said - yes, resolving to the agent is fine. The important bit is that you're returning the Promise. Glad it is working!